# Average sum over infinite series given a probability

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

Let's assume that I have a bulb which fails 10% of the time and it takes 5 seconds to turn ON. So when it fails it also takes 5 seconds, let's says it takes 5 seconds and turns ON and then goes puff and turns OFF. Lets say that whenever a failure occurs the bulb has to go through a cooldown time of another 2 seconds. What would the average total time it would take for the light bulb to turn ON.

We have to take consecutive failures of this bulb into account while calculating the time. So if we consider only 1 failure occurs, then we get

time = 0.9 * (5) + 0.1 (5+2)

Now consider we have two failures,

time = $0.9 * (5) + 0.1 * (5+2) + 0.1^2 * (5+2)$

and so on, to infinite failures we get a geometric series.

sum of infinite geometric series: $\frac{a}{1-r} = \frac{0.1}{1-0.1}$ , where a = first term in series and r = 0.1

time = 0.9 * (5) + $\frac{0.1}{1-0.1}$ * (5+2)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome. Is this format okay? My question is very simple so I didn't add more information. I'll try to explain more if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: It's better now.

Comment: We wait 5 seconds, and 10% of the time we wait at least another 5, so the expected time is greater than $5 + 0.1(5) = 5.5$.  Is your answer greater than $5.5$?  If not, you may want to write out the details more carefully (e.g. where did the infinite geometric series come from?)

Comment: Sorry for missing that detail. So whenever a failure occurs there's a cooldown period of 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at it is -

Probability of success is $0.9$ and probability of failure is $0.1$. Now when a failure occurs you can then have a success with probability $0.9$ next or another failure with probability $0.1$... so on

So $P(avg) = 0.9 \times 5 + 0.1 \times (7 + 0.9 \times 5 + 0.1 (7 + 0.9 \times 5 + 0.1 ...)$...

$P(avg) = 4.5 + 0.1 \times 11.5 + 0.1^2 \times 11.5^2 + ... = 4.5 + \frac{0.1}{1-0.1} \times 11.5 = 5\frac{7}{9}$ which really translates to geometric series of failures plus eventual success.

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to include the success as part of your infinite series, or you just need to note we will always [eventually] have a success.  In either case, we conclude there should not be a $0.9$ in front of the first term.

That is, this gives an answer of $$5 + \frac{0.1}{1-0.1}\cdot(5+2)$$